# Creating Distinct Item List from a JSON

Tags: c#, json

I've got a JSON as follows-

```
[
  {
    "From": "London",
    "To": "Dubai",
    "Duration": "4"
  },
  {
    "From": "Dubai",
    "To": "Mumbai",
    "Duration": "8"
  },
  {
    "From": "Dubai",
    "To": "Dhaka",
    "Duration": "4"
  }
]
```

As you can see JSON has locations in `To` and `From` field. I'm creating the JSON using

```
List<model> list = new List<model>();

         foreach (var item in lines)
         {

           string[] fields = item.Split(',');
           list.Add(new model
           {
            From = fields[0],
            To = fields[1],
            Duration = fields[2]
            });
         }
     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented);
```

And the Model class

```
public class model
    {
        public string From { get; set; }

        public string To { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally I want to create a `List<string>` called `Cities` which will only contain `Distinct` city names from the JSON without any repetition.
i.e. Dubai appears three times in the JSON.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain if you mean the json directly, or the parsed list. Assuming that you meant the list, you can select the distinct elements that you need from your list using Linq:

```
var cities = list.Select(x => x.To).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. It works but I didnt understand the code. Specially `list.Select(x => x.To)` I believe its lambda expression right?

Comment: Yes that's correct, essentially you're projecting your original list into a new list based on a criteria. The way I understand it, 'x => x.To' is selecting the 'To' field from each element as a new list, the Distinct() takes your new list and  and selects on the distinct (unique) elements as a new list.I highly recommend doing some reading / Linq tutorials as you will likely find it beneficial. Here is a good starting point for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx

Comment: Ok now I see a problem.. My requirement is to get the names of the cities from both `To` and `From` field and make them distinct. In the solution above I'm only getting `To` distinct!